# Поведение функции signal в разных компиляторах

Tags: c++, c, signal

Недавно узнал про такую функцию из библиотеки C, как signal, с помощью которой можно установить обработчик, который вызывается при попытке деления на ноль или арифметического переполнения.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

void fnc1(int)
{
    cout<<"SIG"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGFPE,fnc1);
    int one=1,zero=0;
    int i=one/zero;
}
```

На ideone сигнал обрабатывается бесконечное число раз, но на VS2008 никакого сигнала, почему-то, не ловится, а сразу выкидывает. Получается, что поведение этой функции меняется от компилятора к компилятору? Есть ли тогда вообще смысл использовать ее?

Comment: Не на скачках, а в преферанс, не сто тысяч, а десять и не выиграл, а проиграл. Компилятор в данном случае дело второе. А вот системные API -- совсем другой вопрос. И смотреть тут лучше не в C++, а в C

Comment: >> И смотреть тут лучше не в C++, а в C

Угу, и мышку лучше взять Logitech.

Comment: @Waylander123, signal это из мира \*nix. 

В винде (MinGW) есть ограниченная эмуляция (по крайней мере SIGINT (Ctr-C) есть, что есть еще не помню), но для серьезного использования она не годится.

В таких средах, как cygwin и interix дело там обстоит вроде бы лучше.

Comment: @avp Вы бы ещё VMWare-VirtualBox'ы вспомнили...

@Flammable ну signal без хорошей мыши работать не будет.

Comment: @alexlz, а при чем здесь VirtualBox?

В нем линукс (на мой взгляд) нормально работает. Есть, конечно некоторые отличия от железки и VMWare на жедезке, но не принципиальные.

Comment: @avp просто тот же cygwin в принципе некоторые posix-вызовы (fork, select) эмулирует весьма суровым образом, с созданием дополнительных нитей и т.д. Так чего уж мелочиться? (правда под cygwin'ом можно использовать winapi, а всякие virtualbox'ы таких возможностей не дают.